# Эпиграф к статье

Tags: общие-вопросы

Здравствуйте!

Мне необходимо оформить статью, эпиграфом которой является слоган фильма "Дивергент" "Ты опасен, если ты другой". Подскажите, как правильно написать?

Ты опасен, если ты другой.
Фильм "Дивергент"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты опасен, если ты другой.

Фильм  Нила Бёргера "Дивергент" / Divergent (2014) по роману В. Рот

Нет кавычек (эпиграф выделяется в абзац и поэтому не берётся в кавычки). Нет знаков после имени автора или названия произведения.

Answer (score 0):

"Ты опасен, если ты другой".

Рекламный слоган к фильму"Дивергент" Нила Бёргера
   по роману  В. Рот.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил более "книжный" вариант эпиграфа.

Ты опасен, если ты другой.

В. Рот.

Если нет необходимой смысловой отсылки непосредственно к содержанию фильма, то указания автора цитаты вполне достаточно.